# Trying to run a Unix-exec file via MacOS Terminal results in "zsh: exec format error"

Tags: macos, unix, zsh

I'm on MacOS BigSur 11.4. I'm trying to run an executable file to start a Minecraft server from a folder of set up files associated with a Minecraft/Python coding book (https://nostarch.com/programwithminecraft).

My order of operations has been. 1) I moved to the file's path via cd/, 2) set the file's executable bit via: chmod +x ./NAME_OF_THE_FILE, and 3) try running the following command to execute the file: ./NAME_OF_THE_FILE

Another post advised that once I run those commands, going forward I just need to run the third command while in the files path. However, no matter how many things I try to I keep getting a "zsh: exec format error."

I suspect this has something to do with the book's publication being in 2015 when the current version of MacOS was Mountain Lion, which was before they switched from bash to zsh with all releases successive to Catalina. This would suggest I'm just formatting something wrong in a way that conflicts with the zsh syntax, but I can't figure it out. I'm searching around zsh format error related posts and they all discuss actions and conflicts that seem only tangentially related to my issue. Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage and troubleshooting; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask about this. But I'm pretty sure you'll have to provide more info before anyone can help you. What file is this, what format is it in (use `file NAME_OF_THE_FILE` to find out), and does your Mac have an Intel or Apple Silicon CPU?

Comment: How about running `file YourSecretUnnamedExecutable` to see what the file actually is?

Comment: Hi. The file is only listed as a "document" in the Get Info "kind" section. After running the code `file...`, it returns `MacOS Alias file`. 

This Mac is running on an Intel Core i7 processor.

Comment: For zsh syntax, try `dos2unix FILE` to ensure the line endings are correct.  For a binary file, it must have been compiled for your OS - architecture.  Also a 32bit exec **should** run on a 64bit system, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Mezaloid87 : What exactly is a **Unix-exec** file? If you mean a binaray exec file, did you compile it on your Mac?